# FeatureJSON using CompositeFeatureCollection

Tags: java, json, geojson, geotools, web-feature-service

I'm making use of [`FeatureJSON`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/feature/FeatureJSON.html) from `org.geotools:gt-geojson:15-SNAPSHOT` dependency in a Maven project and I'm able to serve GeoJSON for instances of [`SimpleFeature`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.html) and [`SimpleFeatureCollection`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/simple/SimpleFeatureCollection.html) without any problems. However I find myself wanting to serve WFS with multiple feature types and so I added [`CompositeFeatureCollection`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/wfs/CompositeFeatureCollection.html) from the `org.geotools:gt-wfs:15-SNAPSHOT` dependency but when I try and use [`FeatureJSON.writeFeatureCollection(FeatureCollection, OutputStream)`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/feature/FeatureJSON.html#writeFeatureCollection-org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection-java.io.OutputStream-) to write a `CompositeFeatureCollection` I get a `NullPointerException` in `writeFeatureCollection()` due to the implementation of `getSchema()` returning `null` in `CompositeFeatureCollection`.

Do any of you know if these two classes (`FeatureJSON` and `CompositeFeatureCollection`) by GeoTools are designed to work together, and if so how does one do so? Google so far only turned up documentation results when searching for these two together.

To help with troubleshooting this issue I've created a [simplified test project I pushed to GitHub](https://github.com/okwolf/composite-feature-collection-json) showing the working and not working cases as unit tests plus a hack subclass to `CompositeFeatureCollection` that returns a dummy `SimpleFeatureType` and shows how even when this `NullPointerException` is bypassed this is erroneously used for mapping the contents of each `SimpleFeatureCollection` in the list that is passed to [`CompositeFeatureCollection(List<FeatureCollection>)`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/wfs/CompositeFeatureCollection.html#CompositeFeatureCollection-java.util.List-) rather than the `SimpleFeatureType` inside of each `SimpleFeatureCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the GeoJSON module doesn't support more than simple features so there would need to be some development work to bring complex features in. If you were interested then a good place to start would be in the unsupported [GeoJSONStore](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/geojsonstore) which currently provides a ContentStore based DataStore wrapper around the raw GeoJSON module.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. For now my workaround is to create individual `SimpleFeatureCollection`s for each of my feature types and then manually combining the `features` array from each resulting JSON.